# GitLab Setup Trouble with Bundle

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle, installation, gitlab

I dispair here slowly.
I followed the official guide on GitHub setting up GitLab.

Up to "bundle install" anything is allright.
But if I try this here:

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

it hangs on "Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/"

Changing something in gemfile produces more trouble...

And if rake is already installed it fires with this error message:

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What to do here? Why is it more complicated than needed?
If someone could help I would be glad.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this because of some issue with rubyforge? (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5188)

Comment: Or because of a proxy (as in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5075)?

Comment: no proxies, nothing else, its a clean debian 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just solved my problem (after loosing my nerves for 14 hours...)

Up to "Installing Gems" is anything ok from the official guide.

Then I have tried this here:

```
$ sudo bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Than I have downloaded "rake" from http://bb-m.rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.1.0.gem (with wget)
into the "/home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/cache" dir

Gave it all rights (chmod 777 rake....)

And then tried this:

```
$ sudo -u git -H bundle install --verbose --deployment --without development test postgres aws
```

And ->

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the groups development, test, postgres and aws were not installed.
It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
Post-install message from rdoc:
Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:

<= 1.8.6 : unsupported
 = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
 = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
>= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
Post-install message from haml:

HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break
your application:

* Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped
* Support for Rails 2 dropped
* Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags
* Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored
* html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem
* Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem

For more info see:

http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md

Post-install message from httparty:
When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
```